# What causes certain apps on my Samsung Galaxy s21 to have a ridiculous list of permissions?

Tags: android, security, permissions, samsung

So my phone has a number of apps I've installed through the play store as any other regular user, but when I go and check "all permissions" for it, I get a ridiculous list of permissions for apps that never ask for any of them at all. Any idea why this is happening? Below are screenshots of "all permissions" for LinkedIn as an example... thanks in advance.
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvn63.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qslFY.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU7vc.jpg)

Just looking for information  on this problem, have tried to remove said permissions but I can't seem to find out how to, it won't let me manage them at all. I'm using Android 13 on a Samsung Galaxy s21 with the latest oneui.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything unusual in your permissions! They are all part of default permissions in Android, however Android may not ask you to grant them. You can find a complete list of Android permissions here: [Manifest.permission | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)

Also notice each application can define new permissions to restrict resource access in Android

---

Alternatively:
In Android there are 4 main categories of permissions from a user's perspective:

1. **Install-time Permissions**:

   These permissions are shown when trying to install an application, they are granted when you choose to install the application. (see below figure)

[image: install-time permission]

2. **Normal Permissions**:

   These permissions are automatically granted to any application that asks for it. They have low security level and are mostly used for getting usual information from The Android APIs, like "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" ("view Wi-Fi connections" in your first picture)
3. **Dangerous Permissions**:
   These permissions are asked to be granted by user when required (see the figure below). This category contains access for:

   1. Body sensors
   2. Calendar
   3. Call logs
   4. Camera
   5. Contacts
   6. Files
   7. Location
   8. Microphone
   9. Music and audio
   10. Nearby devices
   11. Notifications
   12. Phone
   13. Photos and videos
   14. Physical activity
   15. SMS
   16. Car information*
   17. Install shortcuts*
   18. Read/Write instant messages*

   *you may rarely encounter these permissions

[image: runtime permision]

4. **Special Permissions**:

   And the most sensitive category that you must almost **never** grant access to them for any application, for granting these permissions you will be moved to settings page where you can select whether to give this access or not (see figure below). These permissions are:

   1. All files access
   2. Connected personal and work apps
   3. Device admin apps
   4. Appear on top
   5. Do not disturb permission
   6. Manage media
   7. Change system settings
   8. Notification access
   9. Picture-in-picture
   10. Use premium text message services
   11. Allowed to use data while Data saver is on
   12. Install unknown apps
   13. Alarms and reminders
   14. Usage data access
   15. VR helper services
   16. Wi-Fi control
   17. Turn screen on

[image: Special access]